# get content file and convert it to int php

Tags: php

I'm counting a table content and save the value in file. When there is an insert into this table, another file will be created and I save the new count number. now I want to get this 2 value and compare it. I always get a strong result. 
This is my code:

```
$crc1 = strtoupper(dechex(crc32(file_get_contents('lastinsert.txt')))); 
$crc2 = strtoupper(dechex(crc32(file_get_contents('newinsert.txt'))));  
if($crc1>$crc2){
echo $diff=abs(intval($crc1)-intval($crc2));
}
$querycount="SELECT count(*) from relations";
if (filesize('lastinsert.txt') == 0){
echo "The file is DEFINITELY empty";
}
else if($crc1!=$crc2){                                   //if the lastinsert is different from the new one we create the newinsert file
echo "The file isn't empty";
if($query_run= mysql_query($querycount)){
    while($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {
$res=print_r($query_row);
file_put_contents("newinsert.txt",$query_row);
 }
 }
 }
if($query_run= mysql_query($querycount)){
    while($query_row = mysql_fetch_row($query_run)) {
$res=print_r($query_row);
file_put_contents("lastinsert.txt",$query_row);
 }
 }
```

Comment: What is your strange result?

Comment: this is one of the result 2470247 or the result must be 2

Comment: I strongley recommend to use databases for storing the data.

Comment: no i don't want to save it into database because later i will send the difference and get the last insert content and make some traitement

Answer (score -1):

what do you mean by strong result?i guess what you meant is a string result.
will,for converting string to int,just use this:

```
$string_result=(int) $int_result;
```

of course there are other ways,for example see [THIS](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) one.

Comment: i have tried it before but it's the same result i have get this result 54140

Comment: you have 2 different strings and when you convert them to int they both are the same?that's strange because it never happened to me.use the other solution i gave you.see if it works.